Python process pulls up stuck child process
python file:
def call_with_output(cmd: str, file: str):
    print("# %s" % cmd)
    host = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        try:
            build_data = host.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            print(build_data)
            _write(file, build_data, "a")
        except OSError as error:
            .....
        if not build_data:
            break
    host.wait()
    return host.returncode

Why Python subprocesses get stuck?
Pulling up maven install in the shell executes it properly But when pulling up maven install in the pipeline, it gets stuck in the sub-processes pulled up by python
gdb show this:
futex_wait146./sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h: No such file or directory.private=0,expected=2, futx_word=0x55e8b8d81f10 <init_lock+64>) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:146

Looks like you haven't read the [tour] yet - this would be a good time to do so. Also, please read [mre] - your code sample should be enough to reproduce your problem, but no more. In this case, that means showing how you're using call_with_output at the very least, and probably removing some of the code inside your function. Please read both, then come back and [edit] your question.
